# Take a comma separated string and add it into a command

Tags: bash, command-line, phpmd

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? `DIFFS` contains a comma-separated list of file paths after line 1 (`foo/bar,baz/bat.php`). If I just copy paste that into the rest of what's on line 2 in the actual terminal, I get what I expect. Doing it via the script I'm in just runs forever and then returns a new prompt, no error. I've tried a few things but my bash fu is super weak... :S

```
#!/bin/bash

...

function phpmd() {
    DIFFS=`git diff development --name-only | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'`
    phpmd ${DIFFS} text phpmd.xml
}

...

case "$1" in
somecase)
   somecase ${@:2}
   ;;
phpmd)
   phpmd
   ;;
....
*)
   showUsage)
   ;;
esac
```

Even if I just do this in iTerm, it works.

```
prompt$ DIFFS=`git diff development --name-only | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'`
prompt$ phpmd $DIFFS text phpmd.xml
/path/to/SomeController.php:58  The class SomeController has 1046 lines of code. Current threshold is 1000. Avoid really long classes.
...
```

Edit: It is being called as a `function` in a larger script as follows if this matters. Edited the above code block to reflect. I used these two lines in a standalone function and they worked perfectly so it's something I don't understand about the wider script obvs...

`set -x` output:

```
+ set -x
++ git diff development --name-only
++ xargs
++ sed 's/ /,/g'
+ DIFFS=app/Http/Controllers/TrackerController.php,docker/kubernetes/configmap-php-ini-worker.yaml,src/Packages/CoreFilter.php
+ phpmd app/Http/Controllers/TrackerController.php,docker/kubernetes/configmap-php-ini-worker.yaml,src/Packages/CoreFilter.php text phpmd.xml
```

just looping hundreds and hundreds of times until I Ctrl+C

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: If i understand correctly, the two lines you show work correctly when executed at the command line but not within a shell script. Assuming that is correct, you could add an `echo $DIFFS` in your shell script between the two lines to see if the results are not what you expect.

Comment: One of the first steps in debugging shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. This will make it show every line as it's executing, with variables expanded.

Comment: BTW, get out of the habit of using uppercase variable names. These are conventionally reserved for environment variables.

Comment: There is no sample input, it's pulling a list of files from `git diff` and then should be using them as the first argument of `phpmd`.

When I do this manually, the last line in my above code block starting `/path/to/SomeController...` is the desired output.

When I use `set -x` it gives exactly what I'd expect but it's looping hundreds if not thousands of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the function `phpmd` is "hiding" the `phpmd` program on your path. You should rename your function to something else:

```
function runphpmd() {
```

And update the call site as well:

```
phpmd)
   runphpmd
   ;;
```

Alternatively, you can use [the `command` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) to avoid recursively calling the function named `phpmd`:

```
function phpmd() {
    DIFFS=`git diff development --name-only | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'`
    command phpmd ${DIFFS} text phpmd.xml
}
```

From the documentation for `command`:

> Runs *command* with *arguments* ignoring any shell function named *command*.

Comment: That was it! Thx mate!